# Does EssentialObjects PDF (EO.PDF) support PDF 1.7?

Tags: c#, pdf, c#-4.0

Does anybody know if [EssentialObjects PDF](http://www.essentialobjects.com/Products/EOPdf/Default.aspx) (EO.PDF) supports PDF 1.7? I was trying to modify a version 1.7 PDF. After I saved the PdfDocument, it became a version 1.4 PDF.

```
        var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(@"C:\FilesToMerge\v1.7.pdf");
        pdfDocument.Save(@"C:\PDF-v1.7 saved.pdf");
```

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format), there are multiple versions, such as PDF 1.4 and 1.7. I hope someone has been working on EO.PDF will give me some hints.

If EO.PDF doesn't support v1.7, are there any other .NET libraries recommendation to version 1.7 PDF merging and modification etc.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply said, if EO.PDF can load your PDF and save it again, and if the saved version of the file opens fine in PDF viewers, chances are that EO.PDF supports PDF 1.7 in general. Whether it has high-level APIs for all PDF 1.7'ish constructs, is a different question altogether. Furthermore, library recommendations are off-topic on SO. But given the facts that PDF 1.7 is the state of PDF that became an ISO standard in 2008 and we now have 2016, any non-ancient, general purpose PDF library should handle PDF 1.7 files and support a certain degree of merging and modifying.

Comment: You are right. EO.PDF 16.0.7 open v1.7 PDF and save it as v1.4 PDF. The issue has been solved. http://www.essentialobjects.com/forum/postsm40352_Does-EssentialObjects-PDF-EOPDF-support-PDF-17.aspx#40352